# NestJS Create Base CRUD Service

Tags: nestjs

I am writing my first REST API with nestjs.

I have several entities for which I have to define basic CRUD operations.
I was wondering if there is a way to create a base crud service that I can use in order not to repeat the same code for all entities.
In this base-crud service I would have the four CRUD methods that call the repository in order to actually do the db related stuff.

Basically I was hoping to have a `BaseCrudService<T>` and than have a `UserService` that `extends BaseCrudService<UserEntity>`.
This way I could "override" methods in the derived class to do extra logic business and than call the base method to actually insert, delete etc.

Is it possible? If so, how would you go about to do it?

Comment: You would have to dynamically construct the functions on both the controller and service.  Probably impossible with params in the REST URL.  Maybe you could create some kind of factory on the server. It is nice to be DRY but this could be much more work than it is worth.  I've cut back on DRY a bit in Angular because my code on the components was getting complicated and confusing just so I could have generic http services.  So to keep it simple and clear I plan to have a separate Nestjs controller and service for each module of my app.

Comment: @Preston thanks for your reply! Yeah I understand the controller part, but what about service and repository? Do you think it would be possible? I would still have one service per controller but at least basic CRUD operations would be delegated to the base crud service

Comment: The only way I know of is to use a specific repository for each type of service, just as membersRepository and Members in the promise.  I see no way to make that same service also work for another repo and model.

Comment: I see! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a base-crud service as follows :

```
export class BaseCrudService<Entity extends BaseEntity> {

    constructor(
        public repository: Repository<Entity>,
    ) { }

    async insertAsync(entity: Entity): Promise<InsertResult> {
        return this.repository.insert(entity);
    }
    ...
}
```

And than have the individual services extend that class :

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService extends BaseCrudService<UserEntity>{
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
    public repository: Repository<UserEntity>,
  ) {
    super(repository);
  }
}
```

Et-voilà now you have insert, delete, update etc already taken care of..and this for all services that extend the class.

Following this logic you can easily create a `BaseCrudController`.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, here's my `BaseService` if you happen to use MongoDB: https://gist.github.com/nartc/c93716ecde5837896ffc30feb84c719d

Comment: Furthermore, If you want to extend this idea to controllers, I added the possibility to extend a base controller. See https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/387.

Comment: Excellent, i will edit the answer and include your guys suggestions :)

Comment: It is easy to confuse create and insert function of the repository... that example is quite useful.

Comment: This makes sense, but how to apply authGuard from child controller? 

For example, I create baseCrudController and extend it by UserController and TodoController. Now I want to allow users to only allow add/update to todos but not users and allow admin to do everything. How to do this?

Comment: @ChauTran just to bump this - I'm curious about how that works with creation. Right now, I'm writing my own base service and I can't declare the parameter to be the same as my entity because fields like id, date and createdAt etc. are missing (since they're calculated fields). What do you do about that?

Comment: @robertmain Partial<T>

Answer (score 5):

I've built a package that helps to create CRUD services and controllers without inheritance https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjsx/crud

Comment: Is that still alive?